# Delete specific characters of a string in a Linux shell script

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I need to remove some numbers, a `:` and two `"` from a string, it looks like

```
"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"
```

and I need only

```
9.cgadjka.jsjdaj
```

I'm at linux terminal doing a script for my first time and dont now much about it.

Comment: Did you try with sed? Ex; `echo '"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"' | sed -e 's/://g' -e 's/"//g'` ?

Comment: Welcome, I edited the question removing the `'` surrounding the strings. Is my edit correct?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, in such case the `awk` solution is even simple :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov yeah, I think OP used the `'` only to represent strings, not to be part of them.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, the problem with double quotes is when you use them in echo they do not appear in to the result

Comment: @RomeoNinov indeed, I used therefore the single qs' in my answer for the `echo`, let's wait what OP says about it.

Comment: Is the string stored in any particular way? Is it on a line in a file, or in a shell variable?  Where does it come from? Is it JSON encoded, or encoded in some other way.  I'm asking because some formats adds double quotes around "strings", and this usually means that the strings are encoded (embedded `"` becomes `\"` etc.), so just deleting the outer quotes is seldom the correct thing to want to do. Instead, one may want to do `jq -n -r --argjson string '"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"' '$string | sub(":.*";"")'` or `jq -n -r --argjson string '"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"' '$string | split(":")[0]'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo '"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"' | sed 's/:.*\|"//g'
9.cgadjka.jsjdaj
```

Match `:` and all characters after it, or `"` and remove them

Answer (score 1):

In comment you see solution with `sed`. You can strip these symbols also with `awk`:

```
echo "9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345" |awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

if double quotes are part of the string you should use this:

```
STRING='"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"'
echo $STRING |awk -F'[":]' '{print $2}'
```

where `STRING` contain the string with double qoutes (`"`)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` you can do this:

```bsh
$ echo '"9.cgadjka.jsjdaj:12345"' | grep -Po '(?<=").*(?=:)'
9.cgadjka.jsjdaj
```